# Erro ao importar lib material dialogs no android studio

Tags: android-studio

Essa é a lib que estou tentando importar:
[material dialogs](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs)

Como está o meu gradle:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E o erro que aparece é...?

Comment: Editei e coloquei a imagem de erro. Só acontece quando adiciono a lib, se remove sync com sucesso.

Comment: Tente o seguinte: vá em *Tools* ↦ *Android* ↦ *SDK Manager*, selecione e instale *Extras | Android Support Repository*. Depois de instalado, tente novamente. Isso deve resolver pelo menos o último erro.

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É necessário instalar a [biblioteca de suporte do Android](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html).

No menu, navegue até *Tools* ⇢ *Android* ⇢ *SDK Manager*, selecione e instale *Extras* ⇢ *Android Support Repository*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois de instalado, tente importar novamente. Isso deverá resolver os problemas.